# Walletnotify under windows

Tags: development, wallet-notify

Few questions about Walletnotify under win:

1)  Is this the rigt way to write .py script into litecoin.conf: walletnotify=C:\Python27\python.exe D:\LiVe\listener.py %s
If not, how it should be modified?

2) Walletnotify gives txid as an %s, txid contains number of confirmations. So here is question, at which point happens call to script, on 0 confirmations, on 1, on 1-3(meaning script will be called three times on transaction, when it gets 1,2 and 3 confirmations? On each confirmations?

3) Is there a way to transfer small ltc to own wallets account without transfer fees, because at the moment i have exactly 0 ltc, thus denying me to just test 2 in peace.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your command line looks fine. Remember that %s will be replaced by a transaction id, such as 9de5056696618f22237eb280bbefe94c1d19661de960a1f2c546a0e3a2bc4600.  So if you can run the script at the command line like this you should be ok:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:\LiVe\listener.py 9de5056696618f22237eb280bbefe94c1d19661de960a1f2c546a0e3a2bc4600
```

2) The transaction id by itself does not contain the number of confirmations.  To get the number of confirmations, you'll have to look up the transaction yourself.  You can either use an external service like [blockchain.info's API](http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api), or call bitcoind's [GetTransaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list).

WalletNotify will fire twice for each transaction: the first time that the transaction appears on the network and the first time that a block is published that contains that transaction.  There are no notifications on subsequent confirmations.

3) If you want to move coins between accounts within a wallet, you can use the [move](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) command.  But if you are going to publish the transaction in the blockchain (i.e. send from one address to another, even within the same wallet) then you may have to add a [transaction fee](http://bitcoinfees.com/), depending on your inputs.